# Displaying relational tables in CodeIgniter with simple way

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I just wondering how to display relational tables in CI when I have:

**customer** table like this:

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | John |
|  2 | Jane |
+----+------+
```

And **fruits** like this:

```
 +----+----------+------------+
 | id | customer_id | fruit |
 +----+----------+------------+
 |  1 |        1 | Apple      |
 |  2 |        1 | Grape      |
 |  3 |        1 | Banana     |
 |  4 |        2 | Pear       |
 |  5 |        2 | Mango      |
 +----+----------+------------+
```

And I want a result of something like this:

```
  +------+------------+
  | John | : • Apple  |
  |      |   • Grape  |
  +      +   • Banana +
  |      |            |
  + Jane + : • Pear   +
  |      |   • Mango  |
  +------+------------+
```

Is there any simple way to do that in CI?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join, like :

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('customer'); 
$this->db->join('fruits', 'customer.id = fruits.customer_id','LEFT');

$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Is it possible to do what I ask with a single `foreach`?

Comment: If you need to display the fruits item, then you need a second sub foreach